# MongoDB multiple update isolation

Tags: mongodb

I'm confused about how **MongoDB** updates works.

In the following docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/ says:

> In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single
>   document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents
>   within a single document.
>
> When a single write operation modifies multiple documents, the
>   modification of each document is atomic, but the operation as a whole
>   is not atomic and other operations may interleave.

I guess it means: if I'm updating all fields of a document I will be unable to see a partial update:

- If I get the document before the update I will see it without any change
- If I get the document after the update I will see it with all the changes

For a multiple elements the same behavior happens for each document. I guess we could say there is a transaction for each document update instead of a big one for all of them.

But let's say there are a lots of documents on the multiple update, and it takes a while to update all of them. What happen with the queries by other threads during the update?

- They will see the old version? Or they will be blocked until the update finishes?
- Other updates to same documents are possible during this big update? If so, could this intermediate update exclude some document from the big update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They will see the old version? Or they will be blocked until the update finishes?

I guess other threads may see the old version of a document or the new, depending on whether they query the document before or after the update is finished, but they will never see a partial update on a document (i.e. one field changed and another not changed).

> Other updates to same documents are possible during this big update? If so, could this intermediate update exclude some document from the big update?

Instead of big or small updates, think of 2 threads doing an update on the same document. Thread 1 sets fields `{a:1, b:2}` and thread 2 sets `{b:3, c:4}`. If the original document is `{a:0, b:0, c:0}` then we can have two scenarios:

Update 1 is executed before update 2:
The document will finally be `{a:1, b:3, c:4}`.

Update 2 is executed before update 1:
The document will finally be `{a:1, b:2, c:4}`.

Comment: Thanks! This explains the first question: "They will see the old version? Or they will be blocked until the update finishes?". Do you know what happen with the second point: "Other updates to same documents are possible during this big update? If so, could this intermediate update exclude some document from the big update?"

Comment: "Other updates to same documents are possible during this big update?" => YES, there's no such concept as _big update_ or (I guess you mean) _transaction_ in MongoDB AFAIK. "Could this intermediate update exclude some document from the big update?" => I think so; the question could be simplified as "Could a query exclude some documents if they are updated during the cursor traversal?". And the answer seems to be YES if you have a look at [cursor.snapshot()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/).

Comment: There's a [related post here](https://blog.meteor.com/mongodb-queries-dont-always-return-all-matching-documents-654b6594a827).